# How to install Node.js in CentOS 5.10 with Python 2.4?

Tags: centos, yum, python, node.js, npm

I want to use Grunt on websites we have hosted on our WHM dedicated server.

It is running CENTOS 5.10 x86_64 standard with WHM 11.42.1 (build 21).

It is critical that things do not break, as we have over 20 domains running websites on this single server.

I tried to build Node.js from source but it requires Python 2.6+, and we only have Python 2.4 installed. I read somewhere about installing Python 2.6 alongside 2.4 with alternative install but I don't know how to do this.

I found this question that has a shell script that installs it for you, and Node.js did install, however it created a symlink in the folder I ran it from (bad) and also did not install npm for me.

I am quite savvy but not an expert in Linux, especially CentOS, and cannot fathom how to get Node.js and npm to work on CentOS 5.10.

Answer (score 1):

Installing a second Python intepreter, with a different minor (or major) version number will not interfere with the 2.4 that you have installed at all.

What you should do at the end of the compile/install process is running:

```
sudo make altinstall
```

instead of

```
sudo make install
```

as described in the [Building Python on Linux docs](https://docs.python.org/2/using/unix.html#on-linux).

So just [download](https://www.python.org/download/) the latest (2.7.7) sources, extract the tar file, `configure` and `make`.

You might need to install some development versions of libraries, watch the configure output for potential missing libraries.

Your 2.4 python will still be accessed using `python`. For the newer version you have to use `python2.7` or at the top of any scripts that should use this version of Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

none of which will interfere with the normal operation of the system relying on 2.4 (and any libraries specifically installed for that version).